# Why thread is running automatically?

Tags: python, multithreading

```
from threading import Thread
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hey there, i am constructor")
    def rn(self):
        print("okk")
    
myobj=myclass()
mythread=Thread(target=myobj.rn())
```

In the above code i have only created a thread but i didn't used start method then why it is running?

Comment: Take out the parentheses in `myobj.rn()`. That calls the function, you want to pass it as an argument.

Comment: @Barmar thank you sir

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs on the threading library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html):

> class threading.Thread
>
> *target* is the callable object to be invoked by the run() method.

You are passing in `myobj.rn()`, which returns nothing. Since you included the `()`, you are calling rn and passing the result as the `target`. Drop the `()` to pass a reference to the callable object:

```
from threading import Thread
class myclass:
    def __init__(self):
        print("Hey there, i am constructor")
    def rn(self):
        print("okk")
    
myobj=myclass()
mythread=Thread(target=myobj.rn)
```